# Don't count duplicate entries in MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unique

I have a MySQL Table like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default          | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| _m        | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0                |       |
| Timestamp | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0                |       |
| Address   | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI | 0000000a         |       |
| Message   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | <NO_MESSAGE>     |       |
| Location  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | <NEED_TO_BE_SET> |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
```

There are Columns like this:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------------+
| Timestamp | Address | Message         |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+
| 000000001 | A       | Some Text       |
| 000000001 | B       | Some Text       |
| 000000002 | H       | Some Other Text |
| 000000005 | I       | Some Third Text |
+-----------+---------+-----------------+
```

(I've removed "_m" and "Location" because it's not necessary. Timestamp and Address are censored because its sensitive data)

This table contains signals.
There can be one unique signals which are send to multiple Addreses (Like row 1 and 2)

A unique signal is (should ... be) represented by a unique entriy in the "Message" Field. In this case there

How can i count only the unique signals? (In this case there are 3 of them)

Comment: use `count(distinct message)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
    select count(distinct message) from your_table
```